# Log4j2 programatic configuration not rolling the files

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am writing a program that will create log4j2 configurations programatically. I have a default configuration in my log4j2.xml file. Based on certain data types in a list I have to create/replicate the log4j configurations for each type. The configuration is for dailyrolling appender which is replicated for these types. The logger configurations are created, log messages are written to different files based on data type. But the daily rolling is not happening.

Can someone help as why the rolling is not happening for the types

Here is my log4j2 xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="DEBUG" packages="com.ericsson.tests">
        <Properties>
            <Property name="log-path">C:\Users\ekhaavi\Documents\ClaprProject\logtest\
            </Property>
        </Properties>
        <Appenders>
            <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/ipAddr.log"
                filePattern="${log-path}/ipAddr-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <!-- <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" /> -->
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4" />
            </RollingFile>

            <RollingFile name="DailyRolling"
                fileName="${log-path}/ipaddress/myexample.type.log" filePattern="${log-path}/ipaddress/myexample.type-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" />
                </Policies>

            </RollingFile>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug" />
            </Logger>
            <logger name="com.log.ipaddr.type" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="DailyRolling" level="info" />
            </logger>
            <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

Here is the code for generating the log4j configuration based on data types. Also help me if I need to change to size based rolling

```
    package com.ericsson.tests;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TriggeringPolicy;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig;

    public class Log4j2Running {

        static Logger LOGGER;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFactory","com.ericsson.tests.MyXMLConfigurationFactory");
            LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Log4j2Running.class);
            LOGGER.debug("Debug Message Logged !!!");
            LOGGER.info("Info Message Logged !!!");
            LOGGER.error("Error Message Logged !!!", new NullPointerException("NullError"));



            /**CHANGES TO LOGGER TO DYNAMICALLY GENERATE THE FILES  --**/


            final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
            final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
            Appender app = config.getAppender("DailyRolling");
            LoggerConfig lgcf = config.getLoggerConfig("com.log.ipaddr.type");

            app.stop();
            config.removeLogger("com.log.ipaddr.type");
            List<String> typeList = new ArrayList<String>();
            typeList.add("Data1");
            typeList.add("Data2");
            typeList.add("Data3");
            typeList.add("Data4");
            if (app instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
                for(String str : typeList){
                RollingFileAppender rp =    ((RollingFileAppender) app);

                String fileName = rp.getFileName().replace("type", str);
                fileName = fileName.replace("ipaddress", "10.5.256.12");
                String filePattern = rp.getFilePattern().replace("type", str);
                filePattern = filePattern.replace("ipaddress", "10.5.256.12");
                String name = "10.5.256.12"+"."+str;
                /*RollingFileAppender appender = RollingFileAppender.createAppender(rp.getFileName().replace("type", str),
                        "false", "false", str, "true", "false", "false", "4000", rp.getLayout(), null, "false", null, config);*/
                TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy policy = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy("1", "true");
                 DefaultRolloverStrategy strategy = DefaultRolloverStrategy.createStrategy("10", "0", null,null,null, true, config);
                RollingFileAppender appender =RollingFileAppender.createAppender(fileName, filePattern, "true", name, "false", null, "true",rp.getTriggeringPolicy(),
                        strategy, rp.getLayout(), null, null, null, null, config);
                appender.start();
                config.addAppender(appender);
                AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(appender.getName(), null, null);
                AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] { ref };
                System.out.println(" the level is "+ lgcf.getLevel());
                String loggerName = lgcf.getName().replace("type", str);
                loggerName = loggerName.replace("ipaddr", "10.24.286.19");
                LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger("false", lgcf.getLevel(), loggerName,
                        "true", refs, null, config, null);
                loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
                config.addLogger(loggerName, loggerConfig);
                ctx.updateLoggers();


                }



            }

            /**END OF THE CHANGES **/


            Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("com.log."+"10.24.286.19"+"."+"Data1");
            log.info("Demo1--SHDGSGDHGSHGDSG");

            Logger log2 = LogManager.getLogger("com.log."+"10.24.286.19"+"."+"Data2");
            log2.info("Demo1--SHDGSGDHGSHGDSG");

            Logger log3 = LogManager.getLogger("com.log."+"10.24.286.19"+"."+"Data3");
            log3.info("Demo1--SHDGSGDHGSHGDSG");

            Logger log4 = LogManager.getLogger("com.log."+"10.24.286.19"+"."+"Data4");
            log4.info("Demo1--SHDGSGDHGSHGDSG");


        }

    }
```

Comment: Are multiple server instances using the same log? I had a rolling issue and this was the case for me; the logs couldn't roll because both server instances had a lock on it.

Comment: Logger definition for DailyRolling is wrong. It should be ```<Logger```. Also for size based trigger you should use sizeBased trigger policy don't use any other policy.

Comment: No a single server instance use the log. Also the issue is replicated if I run the program in eclipse and change the windows date and time. The rolling works but the daily rolling doesnot

Comment: If I change it to <Logger in place of <RollingFile for daily rolling then the program is not executing and getting null at line Appender app = config.getAppender("DailyRolling");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was I was not using separate Rolling Manager for different types. By using teh separate Rolling manager solved the issue

RollingFileManager rollFileManager = RollingFileManager.getFileManager(fileName, 
  filePattern,
                                true, false, policy, rstrategy, null, 
  rp.getLayout(), 128, false, false, config);
                    policyupdated.initialize(rollFileManager);